# Mapping to a file with paramaeters

Tags: java, templates

Is it possible to map values to a file with a fixed template?

For example i have a file:

```
bla bla bla dsfdfsf  ldfksj $value asd sdfkl jkdhs f
```

Now i want to map say value 100 to parameter "value", so my output file text will be:

```
bla bla bla dsfdfsf  ldfksj 100 asd sdfkl jkdhs f
```

Comment: replace `$something` with `map.get(something)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database? :)

If you do not want the DB then you might want to take a look on [CsvMapReader](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/CsvMapReader.html).
Some examples of reading with CsvMapReader are available [here](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html#Reading_with_CsvMapReader).
... and writing examples are [here](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_writing.html#Writing_with_CsvMapWriter).